# Is there a way to make an "enter" keystroke click a specific button?

Tags: html, enter

So I am setting up a virtual keyboard with the following keys and input and a master button with a dynamic onclick function. I want to be able to push the enter key and hit that master button, but for some reason it wont work. When I hit the enter key, it will click the last button that I pressed

I tried using this function

```
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                document.getElementById("MasterButton").click();
            }
        });
```

but it did not work. The system recognizes the keystroke, but it might also be just the default.

```
<div id="VirtualKey" style="float:left">
                        <input id="btn1" type="button" onclick="input(this);" class="keypad" value="1" />
                        <input id="btn2" type="button" onclick="input(this);" class="keypad" value="2" />
                        <input id="btn3" type="button" onclick="input(this);" class="keypad" value="3" />
                        <br />
                        <input id="btn4" type="button" onclick="input(this);" class="keypad" value="4" />
                        <input id="btn5" type="button" onclick="input(this);" class="keypad" value="5" />
                        <input id="btn6" type="button" onclick="input(this);" class="keypad" value="6" />
                        <br />
                        <input id="btn7" type="button" onclick="input(this);" class="keypad" value="7" />
                        <input id="btn8" type="button" onclick="input(this);" class="keypad" value="8" />
                        <input id="btn9" type="button" onclick="input(this);" class="keypad" value="9" />
                        <br />
                        <input id="btn0" type="button" onclick="input(this);" class="keypad" value="0" />
                        <input id="btn." type="button" onclick="input(this);" class="keypad" value="." />
                        <input id="btnDel" type="button" value="DEL" onclick="del();" class="keypad"></button>
                    </div>

<div id="Master Input Section"><br><input type="number" step="0.1" id="Student"></input>

<div id="Master Button Section"><br><button type="submit" id="MasterButton" class="button" onclick="">Master</button></div>


    <script>
        function input(e) {
            // Get the TextBox object.
            var tbInput = document.getElementById("Student");

            // As e is the button, its value is the text on it.
            // Add the value to the TextBox.
            tbInput.value = tbInput.value + e.value;
        }

        function del() {
            // Get the TextBox object.
            var tbInput = document.getElementById("Student");

            // Remove the last char in the TextBox.
            tbInput.value = tbInput.value.substr(0, tbInput.value.length - 1);
        }
    </script>
```

Expected Results, enter key will click MasterButton

Update found error code TypeError: input.addEventListener is not a function[Learn More]

Comment: for the record the new format for posting questions is ackward

Comment: So calling the on-click-handler function directly in your key-up-handler is out of the question?

Comment: There are a few possibilities here:  1) There doesn't appear to be a click event attached to the MasterButton button. ( Are you expecting it to submit the form? If so that requires a form tag with an action URI)   2) you're calling `input.addEventListener` to attach your keyup event, but haven't shown where you define `input`; are you sure that's attached to the element you intend?

Comment: whats going on here, is this is part of a quiz function, and the ID for the master button dynamically changes. I went looking for multiple answers and tried pulling that input.addEventListener into my code and tried to bind it to the Enter key, but I am not 100% sure why it didnt work...

Comment: @AlexCarlson `#Master Input Section` and `#Master Button Section` id are invalid. Spaces are not allowed in id nor classes. Also <input> tags are void elements which do not have end tags  </input> unless you are using HTML4 (very doubtful)

Comment: @zer00ne The code for the most part works fine as is. My goal is to make sure that when enter is pushed regardless of default position, that the enter key "clicks" on the Master Button. Most of the code that changes the onclick has not been inputted into this setup. Also The Div id tags are merely for a fast search though the code, and do not affect the code itself but thanks for the refresher on ID tags

Answer (score 1):

```js
var ENTER_KEY = 13;

$(document).on('keypress', function(e) {
  var code = e.keyCode || e.which
  if (code == ENTER_KEY) {
    $("#MasterButton").trigger("click");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could include the button in your solution to show that it really does work.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried using this method before hence this was weird. I scoured most a good portion of the net trying to find a way to get this to work, but thankfully I found it on another post

```
<input type="number" step="0.1" id="Student" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13)
                        document.getElementById('MasterButton').click()"></input>
```

Hope this helps someone in the near future. but this does bind the enter key on that input field to the MasterButton. Note that I only had one input field, and only 1 button that works dynamically with other sections of the code